# Inverse Square Law and Closed Orbits

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, orbital-motion

The definition of closed in this context is that the body will retrace its orbit.

A standard case for closed orbits is the circular case. I know from Bertrand's theorem that the linear restoring force and the inverse square law give closed orbits, but would the elliptical case also be closed? I cannot find a definitve answer from the texts I'm currently using.

Comment: Elliptical orbits are also closed

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification